# Why are there no cluster object in output h2o.kmeans function?

Tags: r, k-means, h2o

I want to use `h2o.kmeans` function from `h2o` package.
Here is my code

```
clust <- h2o.kmeans(data = waterM, centers = 30,  key = "kmeansKey", iter.max = 1000, normalize = T, init = "none", dropNACols = F );
summary(clust@model);
```

The output is

```
            Length Class  Mode   
params           6  -none- list   
centers      25560  -none- numeric
withinss        30  -none- numeric
tot.withinss     1  -none- numeric
size            30  -none- numeric
iter             1  -none- numeric
```

Why are there  no `cluster` object  containing the vector of integers (from 1:k), which indicate the cluster which each point is allocated to ?

Comment: Judging from the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf#page=65) I'd guess sth like `clust@model$cluster`?

Comment: @lukeA output for `clust@model$cluster` is NULL

Comment: Ah I see you already did a summary for the model slot. Well then, maybe it's a bug? The doc suggests it's there ...

Comment: @lukeA I found the answer. But, yes, I think it is a bug :)

Answer (score 8):

When you run h2o.kmeans it just builds the model.

You will have to run the h2o.predict method using the model that you have built to get the data that you want.

Answer (score 4):

There is a function `h2o.getFrame` which get frame by the `key`. `h2o.kmeans` generates the frame with key from `h2o.kmeans`  + "_clusters". So this code gets clusters:

```
clusters <- h2o.getFrame( localH2O, "kmeansKey_clusters" );
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 Gunjan Karun's answer.

Steps I followed:
1. Predict using h2o.predict
2. h2o.cbind with the identifying column in train data set, in my case, customer ID